# When searching through emails in Gmail, how to always exclude hangouts (-in:chats)

Tags: gmail

Every time I want to search through my email, it's slow as can be, because it's also searching through my hangouts history.. I receive hundreds of messages a day, and searching through mail has become quite the chore. Every time I'll have to append:

```
-in:chats
```

to the search terms. Is there any way for Gmail to stop searching through my hangouts, unless I specify it? `in:chats`?

Comment: This question does not fit on stackoverflow site, but it acutally helped me a lot (I was looking for this original command). Can you by any chance move it to some more appropriate forum, myabe super user stack exchange?

Comment: @Line Have got no idea how. Seems like everyone's happy with having it stay closed and here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Was struggling with similar problem. Then asked myself, the Search Function must be found in the Search box itself.

If you click in the search box, you will see an arrow on the right, click on it, and a small box appears.
 "Don't include chats"

There you go !

Comment: as of now, don't know if when answered it worked, this will only affect the current search by including the words -in:chats on the search, and will not keep this setting for every search